# How to add jdbc driver to weblogic server running on docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, weblogic12c, dockerhub

I have successfully installed weblogic server 12.2.1 and created a domain using docker tool box, but when I tried to create a generic datasource for MS SQL server, I am getting the following error:

> Cannot load driver: weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Please give solution how to add this driver to weblogic server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when I installed Weblogic Quick Installer for Developers which was about 209MB.
After some research, I found out why from here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13753/usedriver.htm#JDBCD111

> The WebLogic Type 4 JDBC drivers are installed by default when you perform a complete installation of WebLogic Server. If you choose a custom installation, ensure that the WebLogic JDBC Drivers option is selected (checked). If this option is unchecked, the drivers are not installed.

Granted, the above documentation is for Weblogic 11, but it seems to still apply to 12. I resolved the issue by downloading a separate wlsqlserver jar file (wlsqlserver-12.2.1-0-0.jar) and renaming it to wlsqlserver.jar (according to Manifest.MF spec) and putting it on to oracle_common/modules/datadirect folder.

I also believe if you choose Generic Installer which is about 791MB, it would also install the drivers so you wouldn't have to go through the process I did.